# Why is an IN statement with a list of items faster than an IN statement with a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having the following situation:

I've got a quite complex view from which I've to select a couple of records.

```
SELECT * FROM VW_Test INNER JOIN TBL_Test ON VW_Test.id = TBL_Test.id 
WHERE VW_Test.id IN (1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,[etc])
```

This returns a result practically instantly (currently with 25 items in that IN statement). However when I use the following query it slows down really fast.

```
SELECT * FROM VW_Test INNER JOIN TBL_Test ON VW_Test.id = TBL_Test.id 
WHERE VW_Test.id IN (SELECT id FROM TBL_Test)
```

With 25 records in the TBL_Test this query takes about 5 seconds. I've got an index on that id in the TBL_Test.

Anyone got an idea why this happens and how to get performance up?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this subquery

```
SELECT id FROM TBL_Test
```

returns a result instantly as well.

Comment: Are statistics up-to-date on `TBL_Test`? Please compare the execution plans and see what is different between them. Also is this your actual query or have you simplified it? Wonder if you might be using an unsargable filter in the sub query that makes statistics estimation wrong.

Comment: @Kirill That query performs exactly the same.

Comment: @Martin The difference between the execution plans seems to be that in the first it filters the view a lot sooner. When I use a subquery it pulls up the entire view and then joins it with the TBL_Test

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: Can we see the code for the view, please?

Comment: Mhmm what if you tried 'SELECT * FROM VW_Test  
WHERE VW_Test.id IN (SELECT id FROM TBL_Test)' ?

Comment: I'm using SQL-server 2008. And I'm sorry but I cannot share the code behind the view. I can tell about the view that it's a nested query with some nasty group by's and it does quite some date-calculations. So far I can see the problem is that the view does its filtering after it got all its results when I join it with the tbl_Test.

Comment: @Frank. The result is exactly the same (except that I miss one column).

Comment: @SouthL - You still haven't answered any of my questions about statistics. Also can you look at the actual execution plan and see the estimated vs actual rows that it believes will result from the `IN`?

Comment: @Martin I forgot indeed. The statistics are fine. No fragmentation and such. I originally thought the problem would be the original table, so I created a stripped down (one column) version and called it TBL_Test. The execution plan tells me the estimated/actual from the table was 25/25 and from the view 331/441 right before the join. After the join the estimated/actual was 30/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when using a subquery the database engine will first have to generate the results for the subquery before it can do anything else, which takes time. If you have a predefined list, this will not need to happen and the engine can simply use those values 'as is'. At least, this is how I understand it.

How to improve performance: do away with the subquery. I don't think you even need the IN clause in this case. The INNER JOIN should suffice.

Comment: The thing I don't get is that getting the results from the subquery is also instantly; I forgot to mention that in my question. I'll edit it in.

Comment: @Frank `IN` is implemented as a (semi) join in SQL Server

Comment: @Martin I think Frank's point is that the IN is completely unnecessary, though -- the given query should return exactly the same results if you just completely remove its WHERE clause.

Comment: @Martin From what I can see the query will return the same results with or without the IN? Or without the WHERE, as Matt pointed out.

Comment: @Matt - Ah of course, the first line threw me a bit because it seems to indicate the sub query gets resolved in a separate step that happens before anything else but yes see what you're saying.